# Insert provider for SQLiteObject ionic 3

Tags: sqlite, angular, ionic3

I'm working on a project on ionic 3 angular 4. I have to connect to a database and do other things...
So I have a page (.ts .html .scss .module.ts), a provider where I use sql. So my problem is this, I have this error :

**core.es5.js:1084 

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for SQLiteObject!

Error: No provider for SQLiteObject!**

So in module.ts I added in provider flag i put SQLiteObject. But now I get this new error :

**compiler.es5.js:1540
 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for SQLiteObject: (?).**

Also if I put SQLite it wants always the SQLiteObject provider.Anyway I never use SQLite just SQLiteObject

```
import { SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
```

I google and I found that  SQLiteObject is not a provider but just an interface.

So? Any idea? I can put code but is long, if you have some idea please comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add its class in providers in your app.module.ts file as:

```
import { SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
   //
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, SQLiteObject]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right SQLiteObject isn't a Provider but you're trying to import it as one. It is a class Object used by the SQLite Provider so you can save the object from your constructor and then use it as `this.db` from there. FYI: remove the `import { SQLiteObject }` statement.

```
private db: SQLiteObject;

constructor(private sqlite: SQLite) 
{
        this.sqlite.create({
          name: 'data.db',
          location: 'default'
        })
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
            this.db = db; //set the object to your own var
            db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...", {});
        });
}
```